# C#'s Directory.Move System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, exception, directory, move

Is there a way to bypass the exception as named in the question title? I have absolutely no idea what to do, I need to change the directory names for a whole lot of directories and it would be much faster to programme it, but this exception has cause me some serious headaches... The code isn't complicated, everything works fine except that one line of code:

```
Directory.Move(folderName, path + "\\" + novoIme);
```

Thanks in advance for any sort of help :)

Comment: At least show us the paths you're moving from and to please?

Comment: What values do you use for `folderName`, `path` and `novoIme`?

Comment: Does the exception include any more info? Like in the `Message` property, or in an `InnerException`? Have you tried debugging and looking at `folderName` and `path + "\\" + novoIme` to make sure the paths are correct?

Comment: NotSupportedException isn't among the documented exceptions thrown by this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: You should use the [Path.Combine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of `+ "\\" + `.

Comment: Bypass? If there was an exception it is for a reason. There only way to bypass them is to find the root cause and handle that scenario. Can you give us more detail1,s does this line throw exception for all our directories or just a few of them? If it is only for a few of them which ones?

Comment: The paths are on an external hard drive, labelled Z:\\Film\\<movie_titles>. I know it's not listed as a typical exception, that's what's puzzling me :) It also says "The given path's format is not supported". Not sure what that means, I've used the  File.Move method on all files inside the directories and it gave me no problem. Cheers for the fast replies :)

Comment: And sorry for using "novoIme", which is in my local language, it should be "newName". I know it's no big difference, but I should've noticed it before putting it here :)

Comment: My best guess based on the very limited information you have posted here is that folderName doesn't exist, or path ends with '\'. As @dtb mentioned, use Path.Combine for the latter; its the safer option.

Comment: I am 100% certain that it does exist, as I've run more than a few tests before using the Directory.Move method, just to make sure I don't mess something up...

Comment: @IanZG - Does it work with directories that aren't on your external hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the source and destination paths are on different volumes? `Directory.Move` method [does not support cross-volume moves](http://www.jdsweblog.com/2010/10/directorymove-doesnt-move-files-across.html).

You will have to implement your own routine to do this, or use someone else's. [FolderMove on CodePlex](http://foldermover.codeplex.com/) comes up in my search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference to your project and use this code to rename the directory:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer c = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();
c.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(/*last name*/,/*new name*/);
```

Comment: @dtb: it's a way for renaming directories

Comment: I shall try it out and hopefully it will work. Yes, it doesn't solve the myster of the exception, but at least it will (or should) help me :) Thanks for the reply, which goes to all that posted in such small time :)

Comment: @IanZG - I tend to be weary about including references to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in a C# program unless I'm using CodeDom to compile some dynamic VB code. In this case, it won't buy you anything because `FileSystem.RenameDirectory` just ends up calling `Directory.Move` anyway (with a couple simple sanity checks).

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that source folder exists, try running your application with elevated privileges and see what happens. Also, try forming the destination path in a separate variable, add it to Watches window and see whether the correct name is created.